# How can i filter a attribute from object from array of values in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, filter

I need help.
i need filter a json object like this...

```
data = 
[
{
    "Empresa": "PLANTA",
    "Sucursal": "AEROPUERTO",
    "Producto": "PIZZA",
    "Categoria": "RAPIDA"
    "Total": 84,
    "FPago": "TERMINAL",
    "SegCliente": "SIN SEGMENTO",
    "Origen": "MOSTRADOR"
},
{
    "Empresa": "RIVERA",
    "Sucursal": "CIRCUITO",
    "Producto": "PASTEL",
    "Categoria": "BOCADILLOS",
    "Total": 152,
    "FPago": "INALAMBRICA",
    "SegCliente": "SIN SEGMENTO",
    "Origen": "MOSTRADOR"
}
 ,...
]
```

I get a array from filtres from Categoria like this ['BOCADILLOS','POSTRES'...]
and another to empresa like ['PLANTA',...]
I built these arrays dynamically

How can i filter data.Categoria with values in ['BOCADILLOS','POSTRES'...]

ty for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Array.filter

```js
let categories = ['BOCADILLOS', 'POSTRES'];
let filtered = data.filter((item) => categories.includes(item.Categoria));
```